# How to get blue div in line of yellow div without changing the html

Tags: css, xhtml

How to get blue `div` in line of yellow `div` without changing the html and without using negative top `margin` on blue `div`?

css

```
  <style type="text/css">
      #main {width:600px;border:1px solid red;overflow:hidden;height:800px}
      .float-left {width:200px;height:100px}
      #right-side {float:right;background:blue;width:400px}
      #one {background:yellow}
      #two {background:green}
      #three {background:brown}
      #four {background:orange}
      </style>
```

html

```
    <div id="main">

      <div class="float-left" id="one">
        <img width="129" height="150" alt="" src="jmg.jpg">
      </div>

      <div class="float-left" id="two">bbbbbbb, Abbbbbbb</div>
      <div class="float-left" id="three">+77 (0) 778 16887 399</div>

      <div class="float-left" id="four"><a href="mailto:ccc@cccc.com">ccccc@cccc.com</a></div>

      <div id="right-side">
          <p>hello how are you.</p>
          <p>i'm fine</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**See live example here** http://jsbin.com/uvuyo3/3

Answer (score 2):

position: relative the container, then absolutely position that blue div top right

http://jsbin.com/uvuyo3/4/

Comment: height of `<div id="main">` will not be fixed.

Comment: I'll always stretch to fill it's contents though, so that shouldn't be a problem?

Comment: That's because you have overflow: hidden set. However, you won't be able to get the absolutely positioned element to expand it's container. I'm afraid that is the price you pay. And without changing the markup you don't really have any other option

Comment: Thanks, is there any possibility of any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

If the left column will always be 200px wide, you can absolutely position it:

```
#main {width:600px;border:1px solid red;overflow:hidden;height:800px;position:relative;}
.float-left {width:200px;height:100px}
#right-side {float:right;background:blue;width:400px;position:absolute;left:200px;top:0;}
```

Don't forget the `position:relative;` on `#main`.